# Does 多分 carry a degree of certainty equal to or greater than 50%?

Tags: words, nuances, adverbs, modality

Purely speculating from the kanji, one could quite naturally think that 多分, being "many parts", could lean towards a likelihood greater than 50% that something will happen.

I always thought as 多分 being a quite neutral 50% "maybe", but I just randomly got to think of the above kanji-based possible interpretation and got curious to know if it is just my idea or there is some truth behind it.

Comment: I saw the other post was asking the difference among 最も、非常に、かなり、ずいぶん. I consider  the degree in the order of 最も> 非常に >= ずいぶん >= かなり. This time the certainty in the order of 絶対 >=  必ず >= おそらく、きっと >= 多分。

Comment: I always get the impression that when a person uses **多分ね** it's probably wishful thinking. _The mother of all evil is speculation._

Comment: かなり大事な質問と思います。私の学生はいつも「直訳」のせいで、「maybe」を使って勘違いさせる。

Comment: Since 多分 is an ideograph and たぶん is an phonograph, I use it to mention something by the degree of certainty from 50% to 80%.

Comment: http://mysuki.jp/english-maybe-9691

Comment: @kimiTanaka not sure I understand what you mean in your second comment. Are you saying that somehow there is a difference between using kana and kanji?

Comment: @Tommy Just in my opinion probably not everyone though, I feel 多分そうだろう is more certain than たぶんそうだろう in one's judgement. I might be bit synaesthesia to kanji and kana...

Comment: @kimiTanaka understood. Quite interesting although obviously only applicable to written language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

「たぶん」は、英語の maybe よりずっと可能性が高いと思います。「たぶん」は probably に近いと思います。70～80％くらいの確率（あるいは90％？）かな？と思います。

明鏡国語辞典によると・・・

> たぶん【多分】
>   二 〘副詞〙 《多く下に推量を表す語を伴って》断定はできないが、そうである可能性が高いという話‌​し手の気持ちを表す。おそらく。おおかた。たいてい。

"Will you marry me?" に "Maybe." と返事されたら普通はがっかりしますけど、「結婚してくれる？」に「たぶん。」と言われたらそんなにがっかりしない（どちらかというと嬉しい）と思います。

「たぶん治ります。」と言われた病気が、実は治る可能性は50％だった…とかだったら、きっと怒ってしまいます。治る可能性が低いなら、「治るかもしれない」とか「もしかしたら～～」のような言い方をしてほしいです。

> Purely speculating from the kanji, one could quite naturally think that 多分, being "many parts", could lean towards a likelihood greater than 50% that something will happen.

おっしゃる通り、明鏡国語辞典にも「 〘名・形動〙数量・金額などが多いこと。また、割合・程度が高いこと。」とあるように、割合が高い（多い）とか、大部分、というような意味で「多」+「分」なのだと思います。<sub>（「多分」は当て字との情報がネット上にいくつかありますが、複数の辞書を見ても当て字だという根拠は見つかりませんので、正しいかどうかわかりません。）</sub>

Comment: I guess  Tommy might be wondering the ideograph(kanji) "多分” literally corresponds with the certainty of something is more than or equal to 50%.

Comment: I should ask him directly though, he might be wondering it is okay to think that there is the correspondence between the meaning and kanji itself in a mnemonic sense.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use 多分 when the probability is more than 80%: "probably"

In my mind, 多分≒おそらく≒十中八九.

Comment: According to Wikipedia :「≒」の記号は、”日本などの東アジアの一部地域では「2 項がほぼ等しい」という意味で「≒」が用いられるが、その他の地域や数学などの専門的な文献においては「≃」を用いることが多い。また、数学的な意味以外でも、日本語の文章では「ほとんど同じ」という意図で使用されることもある。”  ここで間違っているとは言えないでしょうけれど、一応念の為に https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AD%89%E5%8F%B7

Comment: Yeah, most native speakers of English don't know what ≒ means, although many probably learn it while they're learning Japanese.  Growing up in the United States, I learned ≈ in school, and I've always used that as shorthand for "about equal" in English.